# Nintegrate providing results much smaller than what is expected

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, numerical-value, approximation, convergence

This is the first time I am posting something here. So, apologies if I make any mistake. I am dealing with a numerical integration in Mathematica-11.0 that has a Bessel function in it. In order to solve it I am using the Module function in Mathematica:

```
yldLst[(α_)?NumericQ, (β_)?NumericQ, (T1_)?NumericQ, (TRH_)?NumericQ, 
   (mx_)?NumericQ, (mϕ_)?NumericQ] := Module[{yldX}, 
   yldX = NIntegrate[(1/(512*Pi^6))*((amp1[s, α, β, mx, mϕ]*(1/(4*s))*
         (s - mϕ^2)*(s - mx^2)*(1/Sqrt[s])*BesselK[1, Sqrt[s]/T])/
        ((((2*Pi^2)/45)*100*T^3)*(1.66*Sqrt[100]*(T^2/Mpl)))), 
      {s, If[mϕ^2 > mx^2, mϕ^2, mx^2, 0], Infinity}, {T, T1, TRH}, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 10]; {T1, yldX}]
```

Here `amp1[s, α, β, mx, mϕ]` is the a polynomial of the following form:

```
amp[s_, α_, β_, mx_, mϕ_] := (-(1/128))*
  ((α^2*(3*mx^4*mϕ^4 - 14*mx^4*mϕ^2*s + 2*mx^2*mϕ^4*s + 19*mx^4*s^2 - 
           12*mx^2*mϕ^2*s^2 + 3*mϕ^4*s^2 - 6*mx^2*s^3 + 10*mϕ^2*s^3 - 5*s^4 + 
           4*(mx^2 - s)*(mϕ^2 - s)*((-mx^2)*(mϕ^2 - 3*s) - s*(mϕ^2 + 3*s))*
            Cos[θ] + (mx^2 - s)^2*(mϕ^2 - s)^2*Cos[2*θ]) + 
         (3*mx^4*mϕ^4 - 30*mx^4*mϕ^2*s + 2*mx^2*mϕ^4*s + 35*mx^4*s^2 + 
           4*mx^2*mϕ^2*s^2 + 3*mϕ^4*s^2 - 22*mx^2*s^3 + 10*mϕ^2*s^3 - 5*s^4 + 
           4*(mx^2 - s)*(mϕ^2 - s)*((-mx^2)*(mϕ^2 - 7*s) - s*(mϕ^2 + 3*s))*
            Cos[θ] + (mx^2 - s)^2*(mϕ^2 - s)^2*Cos[2*θ])*α^2*β^2)/
        (s*((mx^2 - s)*(mϕ^2 - s) - (mx^2 - s)*(mϕ^2 - s)*Cos[θ])))

amp1[s_, α_, β_, mx_, mϕ_] := If[s > mx^2 && s > mϕ^2, 
  Integrate[amp[s, α, β, mx, mϕ]*Sin[θ]*2*Pi, {θ, 10^(-2), Pi}], 0]
```

For `mx=mϕ=0` one can perform this integral analytically using *Integrate*, as the lower limit on `s` becomes zero, also the expression for `amp1[s_, α_, β_, mx_, mϕ_]` becomes simpler. But if I use `mx=mϕ=0` and use *NIntegrate*, the result is at least an order different from what I get by using Integrate. Also *NIntegrate* is giving the slow convergence warning for `mx=mϕ=0`. So I am not sure if I can rely on NIntegrate results for non-zero values of `mx,mϕ` as the result I am getting for non-zero `mx,mϕ` are way smaller than what I expect. How can I ensure the consistency of the code?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the values of \[Alpha] = 10^{-10}, \[Beta] = 0.1, TRH = 10^8. mx,  m\[Phi] can have any values between 1 to 1000, but m\[Phi] > mx always.

Comment: What is `Mpl` in `yldLst`? Its definition is missing.

Comment: Hi, 'yldLst' is the function that defines the module and Mpl is a number~ 10^18. Thank you for pointing them out.